# error NG8001: 'app-sidenav' is not a known element:

Tags: javascript, angular, angular9

Estoy comenzando una aplicación en angular que me está generando problemas cuando quiero modularizar los componentes.

separe la app por carpetas:

```
app/
-- components/
-- pages/
```

cree el componente `pages/home`, le añadi un modulo y un router,
cree el componente `components/sidenav` y solo le añadi un modulo.

**El problema surge solo con el modulo `sidenav`**

que es el siguiente:

**sidenav.module.ts:**

```
... imports

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SidenavComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    SidenavComponent
  ],
  entryComponents:[
    SidenavComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ]
})
export class SidenavModule { }
```

> Se supone que este modulo lo importo donde quiero utilizar el componente

El routing funciona perfectamente, el problema esta con el componente que no lo reconoce como un elemento de angular.

**home.module.ts**

```
... imports

@NgModule({
  declarations: [  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HomeRoutingModule,

    SidenavModule <<----------------
  ]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

intentando buscar una solucion lo importé en mi `app.module.ts`

```
... imports

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,

    HomeModule, <<----------------
    SidenavModule <<----------------
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

nada de esto funcionó.

quiero aclarar que mi router está de la siguiente forma:

**app.routing.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: '', 
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule)
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

y **home.routing.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './home.component'

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
]; 

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class HomeRoutingModule { }
```

> - ya reinicie el servidor
> - angular 9

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que leo en la documentación de [Angular sobre "lazy-loading"](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules), creo que tienes que añadir los componentes que usas en las rutas en la lista de `declarations`:

... imports

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HomeRoutingModule,

    SidenavModule
  ],
  declarations: [SidenavModule]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```